# R apply Return submatrix

Tags: r, matrix, syntax, apply

Given this code:

```
test=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),4)
splitData=data.frame(first=c(1,3),second=c(2,4))
apply(splitData,1,function (x) {test[x[1]:x[2],]})
```

I get this matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    5    7
[4,]    6    8
[5,]    9   11
[6,]   10   12
```

Why don't I get a list of matrices?

Intended result:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    7   11
[2,]    4    8   12
```

Comment: Indeed that does work, as does casting the matrix as a data frame, but why doesn't mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
do.call(`c`,apply(splitData, 1, function(x) list(test[x,])))
```

Or

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(splitData)), function(i)  test[unlist(splitData[i,]),])
```

From `?apply`

> If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’
>        returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’.
>        If ‘n’ equals ‘1’, ‘apply’ returns a vector if ‘MARGIN’ has length
>        1 and an array of dimension ‘dim(X)[MARGIN]’ otherwise.  If ‘n’ is
>        ‘0’, the result has length 0 but not necessarily the ‘correct’
>        dimension.
>   If the calls to ‘FUN’ return vectors of different lengths, ‘apply’
>        returns a list of length ‘prod(dim(X)[MARGIN])’ with ‘dim’ set to
>        ‘MARGIN’ if this has length greater than one.

Comment: I'd like to know why mine doesn't work - it's more a question of understanding the language than finding a workaround.

Comment: From `?apply`.  `‘apply’ attempts to coerce it
     to an array via ‘as.matrix’ if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data
     frame) or via ‘as.array’.`